# Mysql Order By specific string

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find an answer to this one:

Say I have a table like so:

```
ID   Name
------------------------
1    AAAAAAAAA
2    ABAAAAAAA
3    BBAAAAAAA
4    CDAAAAAAA
5    BBAAAAAAA
```

Is there a way I can order by `name` - but - start that order from say `BB` and let it loop back round (instead of from A-Z, go from `BB` to `BA`)

The final result would then be:

```
3    BBAAAAAAA
5    BBAAAAAAA
4    CDAAAAAAA
1    AAAAAAAAA
2    ABAAAAAAA
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `BB` to appear at the beginning you can use:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by case when substring(name, 1, 2) = 'BB' then 0 else 1 end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91d54/2)

If you want `CD` to appear second, then use:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by 
  case 
    when substring(name, 1, 2) = 'BB' then 0 
    when substring(name, 1, 2) = 'CD' then 1 
    else 2 end, name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91d54/8)

Result for second query:

```
| ID |      NAME |
------------------
|  3 | BBAAAAAAA |
|  5 | BBAAAAAAA |
|  4 | CDAAAAAAA |
|  1 | AAAAAAAAA |
|  2 | ABAAAAAAA |
```

Comment: `order by substring(name, 1, 2) = 'BB' DESC` should also work - is there any bad practice about this, and is `case when` preferred? *Update:* With your update it makes a lot more sense to use `case`. Nevermind. :-)

Comment: @h2ooooooo if they only have one to `order by` then you can `order by desc` but if you have a several specific orders then you can use `case`

Comment: This is actually perfect for what I need - thanks! Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: this will put BB and CD strings at the top, unordered, and every other row unordered ad the bottom.. i am not sure this is what the OP wants

Comment: It's not what the question was exactly - however it does solve my actual problem perfectly, so I'm accepting it on the basis that @bluefeet is psychic.

Comment: @BenGriffiths this answer is certanly useful, but i don't think it's correct to ask a specific question, and accept an answer that does something different...

Comment: @fthiella this has been updated to now order the remaining items by name

Answer (score 1):

This will order all rows by name. It will first put rows `>= 'BB'` ordered by name, and then rows `< 'BB'` also ordered by name, making it loop the way you want:

```
select *
from your_table
order by name<'BB', name
```