# How to rank mysql result based on a specific value before others in a column?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table like this:

```
id   name       email               level      memberdate
1    Joe        joe@gmail.com       silver     04/09/2015
2    Peter      perter@gmail.com    bronze     05/09/2015
3    John       john@gmail.com      gold       06/09/2015
4    Jack       jack@gmail.com      bronze     09/09/2015
```

For specific need, I would like to make a query to list people's name with Bronze level first and then the rest. It should also be Order by memberdate DESC ( also applied for the rest of the result), so that the result look like this

```
id   name       email               level     memberdate
1    Jack       jack@gmail.com      bronze    09/09/2015
2    Peter      perter@gmail.com    bronze    05/09/2015 
3    John       john@gmail.com      gold      06/09/2015
4    Joe        joe@gmail.com       silver    04/09/2015
```

Many thanks,

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989435/mysql-order-by-specific-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression inside `ORDER BY`.

**Query**

```
select * from table_name 
order by case when level = 'Bronze' then 1
else 2 end,memberdate desc;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79b65/1)